# Convert regional string to datetimeoffset

Tags: sql-server, excel, datetime

I have a date string in the following format:

```
9/28/2006 5:53:03 PM
```

I need to convert this to a format compatible with a `datetimeoffset` column (e.g. `2006-09-28 17:53:03 GMT`).

I couldn't find any convert function to get this format. Looking either for Excel or SQL Server conversion.

Comment: TSQL (sql server) has a `format` function, search around

Comment: Yes I mean 17:53

Answer (score 1):

To get the explicit string output you asked for in the question, you can do this, however that format is *not* compatible with `datetimeoffset`, mainly because `GMT` is invalid there.

```
DECLARE @string varchar(50) = '9/28/2006 5:53:03 PM';

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50), CONVERT(datetime2(0), @string, 101)) + ' GMT';
```

*String* output:

```
2006-09-28 17:53:03 GMT
```

Since you actually don't seem to want the format you asked about at all and rather need to insert this value into a `datetimeoffset` column, then the explicit format you ask about in the question is irrelevant. Try (and not clear if all your times are in UTC and that's what you want, or if you really meant to translate to GMT, which observes DST IIRC):

```
DECLARE @string varchar(50) = '9/28/2006 5:53:03 PM';

DECLARE @dt datetimeoffset = CONVERT(datetime, @string, 101);

SELECT [UTC] = @dt, 
       [GMT] = @dt AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time';
```

Output

| UTC | GMT |
| --- | --- |
| 2006-09-28 17:53:03.0000000 +00:00 | 2006-09-28 18:53:03.0000000 +01:00 |

That should be compatible with your `datetimeoffset` column. Next time please explain the entire problem.

In either case, please don't use `FORMAT()` for this (as suggested in a comment), especially at scale.

- [`FORMAT()` is nice and all, but…](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)
- [`FORMAT` is a convenient but expensive function, part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7144/sql-date-format-comparison-sql-format-sql-convert/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [`FORMAT` is a convenient but expensive function, part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7145/sql-date-format-comparison-computed-column-materialized-column/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Comment: This output is still a string type. It fails when I try to insert this value into another table of column of type 'datetimeoffset'. Error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @Osceria Then put _the whole problem_ in your question, instead of half of it. You just asked about format and didn't even _mention_ datetimeoffset. We can't read minds.

Comment: Yes Sir! Updated the question now with the problem statement. I appreciate your help